# Did I succeed in putting this table into the first normal form and how do I put it into the second normal form?

Tags: normalization

The table is here: 
[image: 1st normalization]

I'm unable to get it checked currently hence I decided to ask here. I was also wondering how I would put it into the second normal form. My initial idea is to put just the item field and a new item ID field that is a primary key into a seperate table but I'm unsure.

Comment: What are you referring too when you mean checked?

Comment: @SQLDataInTraining Unable to get it checked by a teacher.

Answer (score 0):

Looks ok, you're gonna need a **Customers** table like:

```
--------------------------------------------------
| CustomerId |      Name      |      Address     |
--------------------------------------------------
|      1     | Daisys Cafe    | 27 Bay drive     |
|      2     | Smiths         | 12 Dee View      |
|      3     | Tasty Bite     | 17 Wood Place    |
--------------------------------------------------
```

A **Products** table:

```
-------------------------------
| ProductId  |      Name      |
-------------------------------
|      1     | Bakewell tart  |
|      2     | Danish pastry  |
|      3     | Apple pie      |
-------------------------------
```

Then the **Orders** will look a bit like:

```
---------------------------------------------
|   OrderId  |   CustomerId   |    Date     | 
---------------------------------------------
|      1     |       3        | 2016-11-07  |
|      2     |       2        | 2016-11-07  |
|      3     |       1        | 2016-11-07  |
---------------------------------------------
```

And the **Items** like:

```
------------------------------------
|OrderItemId | OrderId | ProductId | 
------------------------------------
|      1     |    1    |     2     |
|      2     |    1    |     3     |
|      3     |    1    |     4     |
|      4     |    2    |     1     |
|      5     |    2    |     4     |
|      6     |    3    |     1     |
------------------------------------
```